# aws-sdk with node version 6.17.1

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I have a project with node version 6.17.1. It is not possible to upgrade the version at them moment.
I want to use the SES aws service,  so I npm install aws-sdk, can see it in the file package.json, but when I run the project I get error:

```
 Error: Cannot find module 'aws-sdk'
```

I've tried install older versions of aws sdk as version 2.312.0, the the result was the same.
Have anyone exprienced this? Is there a lit of compatible versions?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

try deleting node_modules from your project directory and clear npm cache and then reinstall the right version of the aws-sdk that supports SES and that also works with node 6.7.1

if this still doesn't work then I would say resort to asking this question on aws forms and if you have aws support plan then make a case where the aws techs can get back to you on this issue